# Filtering not working from select

Tags: jquery, datatable, filtering, html-select

I have created a application with dataTable with fixed headers and sorting, the application is working fine but the issue is that I am having a name filtering through a drop-down, which is not working when I select a particular name.

My code is given below.

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this:

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0w1k8hta/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    myTable = $('#myTable').dataTable({
        "bInfo": false,
        "bLengthChange": false,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "scrollY": "300px",
        "scrollX": "100%",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
    });

    new $.fn.dataTable.FixedColumns(myTable, {
        leftColumns: 1,
        rightColumns: 1
    });

    $("#name").on('change', function () {
        filterNames();
    });

    function filterNames() {
        var name = $('#name option:selected').attr('value');
        myTable.fnFilter(name, 14, false, false, false, false);
    }
});
```

Comment: Did you debug to see if any value is being populated at "var name = $('#name option:selected').attr('value');"?

Comment: put `jquery.dataTables.min.js` after  `jquery 1.10.js` and try to wrap the code inside `jQuery(function($) {` instead of `$(document).ready(function () {`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have entered wrong index in `fnFilter`. Find the below working code,

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ur8s1ku3/)

The issue was with `on` event, you should provide the selector to `on` function

or else use

Delegate: It just attaches the event runtime. For more info refer http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

and

Need to use $(this) to get the selected value inside the event handler.

Comment: when we put the select outside then filtering is working, but why it is not happening the same when we put the select within the table header like as shown in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/o2xct89e/1/

Comment: @parag: If you use delegate it fires the event. But the name variable gets the last selected value.

Comment: @Alex : I have updated the answer above (JSFiddle). Check if it works as per your need.

Comment: @AmarKamthe yes this is what I want, can you please explain me what was the issue and what's is the importance of using delegate

Comment: Why using delegate solved the problem? Because I had even used setTimeout to register change event on dropdown, if it is changed during starttime, still it didn't work

Comment: @Alex, parag :  Actually there is no need of delegate as well the "on" event will work if you write it $(document).on('change','#name', function(){}); this way. Alex : The issue was with your event not getting registered correct due to wrong way of writting the event.